# Orthogonal Complements of Root Lattices in E_8

Tags: lattices, co.combinatorics

I have a rather stupid lattice theory question.  Suppose $L$ is a root lattice that can be primitively embedded in the $ E_8 $ lattice.  Is the orthogonal complement of $ L$ in $E_8$ unique up to isomorphism, or for different primitive embeddings could I get non-isomorphic complements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get different orthogonal complements for different embeddings. There are two different embeddings of $A_{7}$ in $E_{8}$ so that for the first embedding the orthogonal complement is the lattice $A_{1}$, and for the second embedding the orthogonal complement is the lattice $\langle 8 \rangle$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that PRIMITIVE embeddings.  I think then that the discriminant groups of $L$ and $ L^\perp $ will be isomorphic, so at least I still have some hope.  I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: According to Dynkin's classification of root sublattices in $E_{8}$, there are only five root subblattices in $E_{8}$ (modulo the Weyl group action) that admit more than one embedding in $E_{8}$. Moreover each of the five admits exactly two non-equivalent embeddings. The five exceptions (and their possible complements) are: 

Comment: $A_{1}^{\oplus 4}$, ($D_{4}$, $A_{1}^{\oplus 4}$); \linebreak

$A_{3}\oplus A_{1}^{\oplus 2}$, ($A_{3}$, $A_{1}^{\oplus 2}\oplus \langle 4\rangle$); \linebreak 

$A_{3}^{\oplus 2}$, ($A_{1}^{\oplus 2}$, $\langle 4 \rangle^{\oplus 2}$), \linebreak

$A_{5}\oplus A_{1}$, ($A_{2}$, $A_{1}\oplus \langle 6 \rangle$); \linebreak 

$A_{7}$, ($A_{1}$, $\langle 8\rangle$). \linebreak

So for the primitive embeddings you get a uniquely determined orthogonal complement.

 

Comment: Thanks so much, Tony.  Could you give me the reference for the Dynkin paper?

Comment: The original paper is: Dynkin, E. B. Semisimple subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras. (Russian) Mat. Sbornik N.S. 30(72), (1952), 349–462. There is also an English translation: E.B. Dynkin, Semisimple subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras. AMS Translations, volume 6, (1957), 111-244. The part you need is in Table 11 in Chapter II. 


Comment: The first time I encountered all this was in the excellent paper: Oguiso, Keiji; Shioda, Tetsuji The Mordell-Weil lattice of a rational elliptic surface. Comment. Math. Univ. St. Paul. 40 (1991), no. 1, 83–99. Among other things they show that both embeddings of all five exceptions do occur as narrow Mordell-Weil lattices of rational elliptic surfaces.  